an android mp3 cutter that clearly shows frequencies ranges
an android mp3 cutter that clearly shows frequencies ranges
When recording audio on smartphone, there is a lot of noise from the ambient.
I need to easily find when my upstairs neigbor pushed his furniture in bully rage, but it is very difficult to find it with all the ambient noise messing the wave graph.
I could copy the mp3 to pc and clean the noise with audacity, but i have health problem that requires me to walk a lot, so sitting to use the pc is not an option.
So, the mp3 cutter should have some feature to at least clear the noise, or show each frequency range using rainbow colors, or let me see only the frequency range i am looking for.
There are hundreds of mp3 cutters.. wich one does what i need?
